# Text file in Java is not created

Tags: java, java-io

I'm writing a program in Java (version lower than 7) that will be executed over a linux machine.

The code is the following, it keeps asking for a file in a directory, and when it is created then an answer file is also created in the same directory:

```
File file;
String filePath = "/mnt/fs_services/pid/data/users/sup/test.txt";

do {
    file = new File(filePath);
} while(!file.exists());

File fileAnswer = new File("/mnt/fs_services/pid/data/users/sup/answer.txt");
try{
    fileAnswer.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code is executed and the reply file is not created when I create the test.txt. Also it doesn't seem to throw an error in any moment, so I don't know what can happen. Any idea about what is happening?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Store fileAnswer.createNewFile() in a boolean variable and try to print it to see what it returns.

Comment: And check if the first loop ever ends: if the file does not exist that loop while never exit

Comment: Hi, the thing is that this is part of an application, and in a particular moment a person will create the test.txt in this directory of the linux machine while the application has been executed. So the idea is to keep listening to this directory referenced by the file variable and when it exists, continue creating the reply answer. I am using Java 6 so I can't use WatcherService and also we are having problems with logs because at this moment they are not working. Thank you

Comment: Please update your question with that details.

Comment: And note: first of all, dont do a "hot loop". Have your code in the loop WAIT a 1 sec or so before doing the next loop iteration. Next: always remember that < java 7 had had end of life many many many years ago. Invest your time updating your infrastructure, instead of working around stone old, insecure technologies ....

Comment: You have already asked a question about this, and it was marked as a duplicate, did you look into the answers for the original question?

Answer (score -2):

Your's do while loop is running forever because line

`file = new File(filePath);`

doesn't create file.

You should change to this:

```
do {
  file = new File(filePath);
  file.createNewFile();
} while (!file.exists());
```

---

**EDIT:
I missed point with my answer, sorry for that.
I did test that problem on my linux, i did make function like that:**

```
File file;
do {
    file = new File("/etc/ssl/private/test.txt");
    System.out.println(file);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
while (!file.exists());
try {
    file = new File("/etc/ssl/private/test2.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Explanation of example:

1. executing command "cd /etc/ssl/private" in terminal results in "Permission denied"
2. System.out.println(file) returns "/etc/ssl/private/test/test.txt"
3. adding file test.txt to path /etc/ssl/private with sudo command works
4. Java program won't get out from loop still

So my guess is that your java application doesn't have a permission to read "/mnt/fs_services/pid/data/users/sup/" and that's why your program is not working.

Btw. when i did set filePath to /home/test.txt the app did worked.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that this is part of an application, and in a particular moment a person will create the test.txt in this directory of the linux machine while the application has been executed. So the idea is to keep listening to this directory referenced by the file variable and when it exists, continue creating the reply answer. I am using Java 6 so I can't use WatcherService and also we are having problems with logs because at this moment they are not working. Thank you

Comment: @IvanSanchez I did edited my answer. I hope this will help you

Comment: What permissions should have the first file (the first that is read from the directory)?

Comment: It's about the folder that first file is in. Your java process need to have read permission for path "/mnt/fs_services/pid/data/users/sup/"

Comment: How can I give permissions to the java process? It is supposed that at the beginning the file does not exist and when it is created, the exists() method will return true and the execution continues creating the new one. The thing is that the code doesn't seem to give error in any moment, is like it is forever in the loop checking for the existence of the file (the path is correct). Maybe can be because of Thread.sleep()? (I don't have it) Thank you so much for your interest!

Comment: You can run java process with "sudo". You can change owner of your directory for same as java process etc. Here its basically a linux fun to make the magic happens

Comment: try to use function "canRead()" on your first file and check the result of it

Comment: Anyway, at this moment what i need is just to know if it exists in the directory, the content for me is not relevant at this time